# Compare data vector

Tags: java, sql, vector

The program firstly will load `"Type"`  from sql to vector. Then it will compare with `String a` . If the value in `"Type"` is equal to `a`, it will return 0.1. If not, it will return 0.0.

But when I compile, I get this output even though the `a` is equals to  `"Type"`. Why ?

```
0.0
0.0
```

**Code**

```
  public void CompareType(Double[] b,String a,int[] array ) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double c ;
        String sql="Select Type from menu ";
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ArrayList<String> vector=new ArrayList<String>(); 
        vector.add("Type");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Vector<Double> value1 = new Vector<Double>();
         Double[] array4 = new Double[2];
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
        ArrayList<String> r=new ArrayList<String>(); 
        r.add(rs.getString("Type"));
        if(a.equals(r))
        {
            c=10/100;
            System.out.println(c);
            value1.add(c);
            value1.copyInto(array4);

        }
        else
        {
            c=0;
            value1.add(c);
            value1.copyInto(array4);

        }


         }
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(array4[i]);
        }
    /*  ComparePre(b,array4,array);
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();*/

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code `10/100` performs Java's integer division, because both operands are `int`s.  As division by `int`s must yield an `int`, the result is the truncated `int` -- `0`.  It doesn't matter that the result will be assigned to a `double`; the division has already occurred at that point.

Either use a `double` literal:

```
10.0/100
```

or cast an operand as a `double`:

```
(double) 10/100
```

or just initialize it directly:

```
c = 0.1;
```

The other problem is that your are attempting to compare an `ArrayList` (called `r`) with the `String` (called `a`).  An `ArrayList` will never be equal to a `String`.  It's unclear why you created an `ArrayList` with one element just to compare that element with what's coming back from your database.  It's unnecessary.  Just compare the strings directly.

```
// May want to check for null here.
String r = rs.getString("Type");
if (a.equals(r))
{
```

Comment: I've added more to my answer.